# Json encode returning undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have multidimensional array in PHP which I have converted into json using json encode. Now when I do console.log in javascript it shows undefined.

When I do JSON.parse the error shows

```
jquery.js:687 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

**This is my json encoded data**

```
"{"select_data":[{"id":10563,"fullname":"Raj Bahadur Thapa","created_by":121,"company_id":68,"company_name":"WhiteHat","selected_at":"2019-10-03 12:14:18","t_count":1,"p_count":3.571428571428571},{"id":10554,"fullname":"Sebastian Antony Sahayan","created_by":121,"company_id":19,"company_name":"Concentrix","selected_at":"2019-10-03 11:22:15","t_count":3,"p_count":10.714285714285714},{"id":10545,"fullname":"Natasha Fernandes","created_by":121,"company_id":21,"company_name":"Firstsource","selected_at":"2019-10-03 10:37:59","t_count":3,"p_count":10.714285714285714},{"id":10537,"fullname":"Farahnaaz Khan","created_by":121,"company_id":90,"company_name":"Hexaware","selected_at":"2019-10-03 10:08:17","t_count":2,"p_count":7.142857142857142},{"id":9788,"fullname":"Saneesh M","created_by":121,"company_id":11,"company_name":"Tele Performance ","selected_at":"2019-10-03 09:58:38","t_count":19,"p_count":67.85714285714286}],"p_count_arr":[3.571428571428571,10.714285714285714,10.714285714285714,7.142857142857142,67.85714285714286]}"
```

**Laravel QUERY**

```
public function company_wise_select()
    {

        $sub_query = DB::table('in_lineups_tracker')
            ->join('in_lineups', 'in_lineups.id', '=', 'in_lineups_tracker.candidate_id')
            ->join('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'in_lineups.company_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'in_lineups.created_by')
            ->where([
                ['in_lineups_tracker.status', 19],
                ['in_lineups_tracker.type', 3],
                ['users.id', 405]
            ])
            ->groupBy('in_lineups.id')
            ->select(
                'in_lineups.id',
                'in_lineups.fullname',
                'in_lineups.created_by',
                'companies.id as company_id',
                'companies.name as company_name',
                'in_lineups_tracker.created_at as selected_at'
            );

        $el_query = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub_query->toSql()}) as table_001"))
            ->mergeBindings($sub_query)
            ->select(
                '*',
                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as t_count')
            )
            ->groupBy('table_001.company_id')
            ->orderBy('table_001.selected_at', 'DESC')
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();


        $totalCount = $el_query->sum('t_count');

        foreach ($el_query as $select)
        {
            $select->p_count = ($select->t_count/$totalCount) * 100;
            $p_count_arr[] = $select->p_count;
        }

        $data['select_data'] = $el_query;
        $data['p_count_arr'] = $p_count_arr;
        return json_encode($data);

    }
```

How can I json decode it in javascript and utilize the data?

Comment: Can you show that php code?

Comment: Your JSON is incorrect, Try [JSON VALIDATE](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: It's undefined? Error seems to be questioning the validity of JSON instead.

Comment: The value you posted as "json encoded data" is neither JSON, nor a JavaScript string. How do you transfer the data from the PHP script to the JavaScript code? Do you use Ajax or the PHP code generates the JavaScript code?

Comment: I am json encoding Laravel collection

Comment: I have updated the question with PHP code. Why my JSON is not a valid JSON and how can I make it valid?

Comment: Your JSON has an extra set of double quotes surrounding it. It should start / end with `{}`

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
<script>
var data= <?= json_encode($array) ?>
console.log(data);
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to go by this method. I am ecoding my data backend side only but javascript is says data is undefined

Answer (score -1):

**You can use JSON.stringify() to acheive this**

```
var JsonObj = <?php echo $json;?>;
var myJsonData = JSON.stringify(JsonObj);

console.log(myJsonData);
```

Comment: No they can't. See the first sentence of the question which says the raw data is in PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: You can replace your PHP variable by adding <?php echo $json; ?> in JsonObj